# Converting Python dict to kwargs?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I want to build a query for sunburnt (solr interface) using class inheritance and therefore adding key-value pairs together. The sunburnt interface takes keyword arguments. How can I transform a dict (`{'type':'Event'}`) into keyword arguments (`type='Event'`)?

---

<sub>See also: [What do ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) mean in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847) - the corresponding question for people who encounter the syntax and are confused by it.</sub>

Comment: **See also:** [python dictionary unpacking pep448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/)

Answer (score 836, accepted):

Use the [double-star](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (aka [double-splat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator/2322384#2322384)) operator:

```
func(**{'type':'Event'})
```

is equivalent to

```
func(type='Event')
```

Comment: and if you already have a dict object called "myDict" you just `func(**myDict)` 
.i.e `myDict = {"type": "event"}`

Comment: This is pretty well-covered in the python standard documentation. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137161. (dmid://juice_cobra_hush)

Comment: This is brilliantly helpful, especially when using converting dictionaries into Swagger model instances. Thanks.

Answer (score 49):

`**` operator would be helpful here.

`**` operator will unpack the dict elements and thus `**{'type':'Event'}` would be treated as `type='Event'`

`func(**{'type':'Event'})` is same as `func(type='Event')` i.e the dict elements would be converted to the `keyword arguments`.

FYI

`*` will unpack the list elements and they would be treated as `positional arguments`.

`func(*['one', 'two'])` is same as `func('one', 'two')`

Answer (score 18):

Here is a complete example showing how to use the `**` operator to pass values from a dictionary as keyword arguments.

```
>>> def f(x=2):
...     print(x)
... 
>>> new_x = {'x': 4}
>>> f()        #    default value x=2
2
>>> f(x=3)     #   explicit value x=3
3
>>> f(**new_x) # dictionary value x=4 
4
```