# Python __dict__ conversion to kwargs

Tags: python

I want to build a query for sunburnt(solr interface) using class inheritance and therefore adding key - value pairs together. The sunburnt interface takes keyword arguments. How can I transform a dict ({'type':'Event'}) into keyword arguments (type='Event')?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using dictionary unpacking:

```
dct = dict({'type':'Event'})

# equivalent to func(type='Event')
func(**dct)
```

Comment: What is the point of `dict()`? `{'type':'Event'}` is already a dict.

Comment: Copied OPs code for his sake.

Comment: @SiyuanRen: It was in the original question. Maybe ask them? (ie, ask teaforthecat at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710391/converting-python-dict-to-kwargs)