# How to pass a variable to python (selenium Webdriver) package function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have the following requirement.
I should be able to dynamically provide port number to the params to pass in

```
webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(<PARAMS HERE>)
```

I tried many combinations but unable to figure it out

```
command = "command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT"
driver = webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(command)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sel2.py", line 38, in <module>
  driver = webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(command)

  File "/home/sysqe/my36project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise WebDriverException("Desired Capabilities can't be None")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Desired Capabilities can't be None
```

it should be able to interpolate the var command and put the params in the place.

Comment: where is pip in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for the key word args:

```
command = {
    command_executor: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', 
    desired_capabilities: webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT
}
driver = webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(**command)
```

see:

- [Converting Python dict to kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710391/converting-python-dict-to-kwargs)