# Python: Modify the json type column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using python3 and pandas version 0.25. 
I have a JSON datatype in postgresql table. I am using pandas.io.sql to fetch the data from the table.

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
df = psql.read_sql(sql,con,params=params)
```

So I am getting the dataframe from DB call as above.

When I check the output of the df (using IDE), I see the dataframe with following:
[image: DF Output]

**Now, when I try to see the dtypes of the columns I see "object" for both the columns.**

I want to update the columns and append value of the json, so it becomes:
[image: DF modified]

I am unable to do the same.

I tried doing the below:

```
df.loc[:, 'col2_data'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col2_data'].append({'multiplier':'2'}), axis=1)
```

But after the above statement, it is giving None for col2_data. i.e. is it not working.

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each value is a list, we can use `.update` method of a dictionary to add new value. This might work in your case:

**Method 1**

```
df.loc['col2_data'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x.update({'multiplier':'2'}) for x in row['col2_data']], axis=1)
```

**Method 2**

```
df.loc['col2_data'] = df.apply(lambda row: [{**x, **{'multiplier':'2'}} for x in row['col2_data']], axis=1)
```

Comment: It is strange.
So, when I tried exactly as above it didn't work. In a sense it updated the value of col2_data as [None] (row 1) and [None,None] (row2).
However, when I tried below (just tried to create the new column:

df.loc['col2_data_new'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x.update({'multiplier':'2'}) for x in row['col2_data']], axis=1)

The new column, col2_data_new is exactly like above i.e. [None] (row 1) and [None,None] (row2). However, old columnd col2_data now had the new attribute added somehow!!
Again, I am not sure, is it because .update or .append method does not work on dtype object

Comment: `.update` method returns none and updates the dictionary in place.

Comment: Thanks @YOLO. Method 2 worked for me. Can you please explain usage here, i.e. double asterik's use or point to documentation for reference?

Comment: glad to know, here you can read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710391/converting-python-dict-to-kwargs

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have some related question, I have asked the separate question. If you can help, it will be great, thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969590/pandas-groupby-and-aggregate-multiple-columns-of-type-json-float