# Pandas: Groupby and aggregate multiple columns of type json, float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using python3 and pandas version 0.25. I have a JSON datatype in postgresql table. I am using pandas.io.sql to fetch the data from the table.

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
df = psql.read_sql(sql,con,params=params)
```

So I am getting the dataframe from DB call as above.

When I check the output of the df (using IDE), I see the dataframe with following:

[image: DF]

I want to aggregate the data; for the sake of simplicity selected 3 columns only. I need to group by col1_data. I want like below:

[image: DF out]

Basically, it is aggregate on multiple columns. But the main issue is merging the json column. Which aggregate function can help me here?

Based on previous help, to use lambda to merge json columns, I tried to do it as below. However, it is not working. I tried to first work with json column, other can be simple sum.

```
df = df.groupby(['col1_data']).apply(lambda row: [{**x} for x in row['col2_data']])
```

I am getting the error:

```
'list' object is not a mapping
```

Can someone help me here? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Following code can be used to create the sample dataframe:

```
import collections
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'col1_data': ['A1', 'A1'],
    'col2_data': [[{"scenario": 1, "scenario_name": "Test", "value": "100"}], [{"scenario": 1, "scenario_name": "Test1", "value": "10"}, {"scenario": 2, "scenario_name": "Test2", "value": "500"}]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 1000):  # more options can be specified also
    print(df)
```

So I need to groupby on col1_data, and col2_data should be merged json as shown above.

**UPDATE 2:**

The solution worked for above data set.
However, when I have 2 unique values in col1_data, it does not work.

```
data = {
    'col1_data': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2'],
    'col2_data': [[{"scenario": 1, "scenario_name": "Test", "value": "100"}], [{"scenario": 1, "scenario_name": "Test1", "value": "10"}, {"scenario": 2, "scenario_name": "Test2", "value": "500"}],[{"scenario": 1, "scenario_name": "Test", "value": "10"}], [{"scenario": 1, "scenario_name": "Test1", "value": "110"}, {"scenario": 2, "scenario_name": "Test2", "value": "1500"}]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The output of DF:

```
  col1_data  \
0        A1   
1        A1   
2        A2   
3        A2   

                                                                                                                 col2_data  
0                                                               [{'scenario': 1, 'scenario_name': 'Test', 'value': '100'}]  
1    [{'scenario': 1, 'scenario_name': 'Test1', 'value': '10'}, {'scenario': 2, 'scenario_name': 'Test2', 'value': '500'}]  
2                                                                [{'scenario': 1, 'scenario_name': 'Test', 'value': '10'}]  
3  [{'scenario': 1, 'scenario_name': 'Test1', 'value': '110'}, {'scenario': 2, 'scenario_name': 'Test2', 'value': '1500'}]
```

Now, when I run the same funtion, I get the following error:

```
df = (df
     .groupby('col1_data')['col2_data']
     .apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x).tolist())
     .reset_index())
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    724             try:
--> 725                 result = self._python_apply_general(f)
    726             except Exception:

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    741     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
--> 742         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
    743 

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    236             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
--> 237             res = f(group)
    238             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):

<ipython-input-109-61a2e6a29020> in <lambda>(x)
      6      .groupby('col1_data')['col2_data']
----> 7      .apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x).tolist())
      8      .reset_index())

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1067         try:
-> 1068             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1069 

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: It would help people answer your question if you made your code [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sure it is the part of bigger code, but let me try quickly to have something which can help. I will update my question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can try:

```
import numpy as np

f = (df
     .groupby('col1_data')['col2_data']
     .apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x).tolist())
     .reset_index())

 col1_data                                          col2_data
0        A1  [{'scenario': 1, 'scenario_name': 'Test', 'val...
```

**Solution two:**

```
f = (df
    .groupby('col1_data')['col2_data']
    .apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x.values))
    .reset_index())
```

Comment: Thanks again. It works for my sample data, I will try for my actual data, which has lots of columns.

However, when I see groupby doc for pandas, I do not see anything in square bracket after list of columns. Basically, groupby([list of cols])['col2_data']; here what does it signify?

Between groupby and apply, we gave the json column on which I need to aggregate in square brackets, so what does it imply?

Comment: Hi @YOLO, Please check the 2nd update. If I give more unique value to col1_data, this fails. Any idea why it fails?

Comment: @Mihir it was failing because `np.concatenate` received a series as input whereas it should be an array, `.values` would fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
new_dat = {col:[] for col in df.columns}
for key,val in df.groupby('col1_data'):
    new_dat['col1_data'] += [key]
    new_dat['col2_data'] += [[dic for lst in val['col2_data'] for dic in lst]]
new_df_1 = pd.DataFrame(new_dat)

col1_data                                          col2_data
0        A1  [{'scenario': 1, 'scenario_name': 'Test', 'val...
1        A2  [{'scenario': 1, 'scenario_name': 'Test', 'val...
```

Or in the same style as @YOLO's answer:

```
new_df_2 = (df
     .groupby('col1_data')['col2_data']
     .apply(lambda x: [dic for lst in x for dic in lst])
     .reset_index())

 col1_data                                          col2_data
0        A1  [{'scenario': 1, 'scenario_name': 'Test', 'val...
1        A2  [{'scenario': 1, 'scenario_name': 'Test', 'val...
```