How to pass *args argument to Python function as a string
I'm using pytubefix to make a Youtube downloader.
The API allows me to write code like:
YouTube(url).streams.filter(progressive=True)
But suppose I have a string stored in a variable like
args = "progressive=True"
How can I use the args string to call the function, as if I specified the same keyword arguments directly?
If I try
YouTube(url).streams.filter(args)
that doesn't do what I want.

Why do you have that as a string in the first place?

Usually you would pass a dict as kwargs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710391/converting-python-dict-to-kwargs

I assume your downloader has a command-line interface - otherwise, where does url come from? This would suggest the args variable also comes from the command-line, or perhaps a configuration file. In either case, you need to use a dedicated parser (e.g. argparse, configparser, json, etc) to convert the input into form that can be passed as function arguments.

Your input string is valid Python code, so if the string does not come from user input, you may conveniently execute it as Python code to populate an empty dict as locals namespace so that it can be unpacked as keyword arguments to a call to YouTube(url).streams.filter:
args = "progressive=True"
namespace = {}
exec(args, {}, namespace)
YouTube(url).streams.filter(**namespace)


OTOH, if it doesn't come from external user-supplied sources, then why use a string in the first place and not a dict…?

Well the string may for example come from a configuration file on a secure host, but yeah it is certainly quite likely that the string is user-supplied. Just throught I'd offer this approach for completeness sake.

Thank you, that works! I still don't really understand why it has to be a dictionary of all things, but it works!

@reChords You're welcome. Keep in mind again that this solution would be unsafe if the string is derived from user input. Variable keyword arguments are a number of name-value pairs so it was naturally decided that a dict would be the most fitting data structure to represent them.

You can simply split the argument string on "=" to separate the two components. However, in your example, a simple split will give you two strings but you need a bool so...
def myfunc(*, progressive):
    print(progressive)

args = "progressive=True"
k, v = args.split("=")
myfunc(**{k:v=="True"})


You can't pass keyword arguments as strings.
What you can do is parse it yourself into a suitable structure.
import re
kwargs = {x[0]: x[1] for x in re.findall(r"([^;=]+)=([^;=]+)", args)}
YouTube(url).streams.filter(**kwargs)

I arbitrarily added ; as a separator so you can say args = "foo=bar;baz=quux"
This simply assumes that all values are strings. If you need to parse e.g. "False" into the proper boolean value False, or support int or float numbers, obviously add the required logic for that.

In this case this'd pass True as a string though, which'll probably fail. To correctly handle that, you need more code which will become more and more cumbersome and ill defined. Just not playing is the only correct answer here.

"True" is "truthy" so it might actually work. It's not going to work for keyword arguments which need to be numbers, or "False" vs False Updated to note this in the answer itself.
